# Paho MQTT client failing for special payloads (forward slashes) when using OpenVPN (Windows)

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have been struggeling with a strange case of random client MQTT publish failing for certain payloads. It happends randomly when trying to publish some large amount of BASE64 data.

I've finally managed to narrow it down to payloads containing a lot of consequtive forwards slashes (/). I've searched the net to find a good reason why this happends, but havent found anythong. Is it a MQTT feature, a Paho client feature or a broker feature, or just some bug...

Setup:

- Python 3.8.8 (Windows 10)
- paho-mqtt 1.5.0
- mosquitto 1.6.9-1 amd64

On my setup, it fails when I send a payload of 255 '/' to a 1 character topic 'a'. Larger topic length, reduces the possible number of forward slashes.

Code to reproduce error:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt_client
import time

address = 'some.server.com'
port = 1883

connected = False

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    global connected
    connected = True
    print("Connected!")

client = mqtt_client.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(host=address, port=port, keepalive=60)
client.loop_start()

while not connected:
    time.sleep(1)

payload = '/'*205
print('Payload: {}'.format(payload))
client.publish(topic='a', payload=payload)

time.sleep(2)

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
print('Done!')
```

This generates this output:

```
Connected!
Payload: /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Connected!
Done!
```

This produces the following error in `/var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log` for the mosquitto broker:

```
1616605010: New connection from a.b.c.d on port 1883.
1616605010: New client connected from a.b.c.d as auto-CEF15129-E74C-F00A-A6FA-5B5FDA0CEF1D (p2, c1, k60).
1616605011: Socket error on client auto-CEF15129-E74C-F00A-A6FA-5B5FDA0CEF1D, disconnecting.
1616605012: New connection from a.b.c.d on port 1883.
1616605012: New client connected from a.b.c.d as auto-0149B6DB-5997-9E08-366A-304F21FDF2E1 (p2, c1, k60).
1616605013: Client auto-0149B6DB-5997-9E08-366A-304F21FDF2E1 disconnected.
```

I observe that the client() connects twice, but do not know why, but this is probably caused by a disconnect...

Any Ideas?

*Update 1: I've tested this on Linux Ubunit running Python 3.7.3, and same paho-mqtt version, and this does* ***not*** *produce the same error...* Seems like some problem in Windows then.

*Update 2:*
I also tried running `mosquitto_pub` and experienced the same error, so this has to be Windows-related (or system related) in some way. Possibly firewall? I will close question if I find manage to solve this.

```
"C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto_pub.exe" -h some.server.com -t a -m '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////'
```

*Update 3* The issue is related to OpenVPN. I closed my open VPN connection and MQTT messages were passing! I'm running OpenVPN Client (Windows version 3.2.2 (1455). I have no idea what causes this conlflict...

Comment: Probably a packet fragmentation problem, is OpenVPN using UDP or TCP?